# Ruby sorting array order by integer in string

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I've got a file that I read in the values from and place into an array so I can sort them:

input.txt

```
#75 - Hamilton Ave.
#12A - Long Road
#12B - Long Road
#120 - Curvy Road
```

My ruby:

```
result = []
file = open("input.txt").each do | line |
  result << line
end
puts result.sort_by {|x| x.to_i}.reverse
```

I want to sort by the integer value in the string. However the order comes out as:

```
#12A - Long Road
#12B - Long Road
#120 - Curvy Road
#75 - Hamilton Ave.
```

Instead of:

```
#12A - Long Road
#12B - Long Road    
#75 - Hamilton Ave.
#120 - Curvy Road
```

Should I be using some sort of regex to eval the string when sorting?

Comment: Is "#" the first character of each line? If not you should edit that out. `"# 123anything"` will always be zero.

Comment: Yes it is part of the string

Comment: Then you want `result.sort_by {|x| x[1..-1].to_i}.reverse`. For example `"#74 - Hamilton Ave."[1..-1] #=> "74 - Hamilton Ave."`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland this will put 12B ahead of 12A without the reverse and with the reverse will not come out in the requested order instead `result.sort_by {|x| [x[1..-1].to_i,x]}` so the full string can be used as the tie breaker.

Comment: @engineersmnky, yes, I initially missed that, as well as the errant `reverse`l. By the time I noticed those two things Mr. Jordan had posted his solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regular expression like `/\d+/` to extract the digits from the string and `to_i` to turn it into an integer, e.g.:

```
input.each_line.sort_by {|line| line[/\d+/].to_i }
```

To keep `12A` before `12B`, return an array from the block, e.g. `[ line[/\d+/].to_i, line ]`. This way, if two lines have the same integer, it will order those two lines alphabetically. This assumes there will only be a `#` before the digits in question, and that each line will have at least one digit.

```
input = <<END
#75 - Hamilton Ave.
#12A - Long Road
#12B - Long Road
#120 - Curvy Road
END

result = input.each_line.sort_by do |line|
  [ line[/\d+/].to_i, line ]
end

p result
# => [ "#12A - Long Road\n",
#      "#12B - Long Road\n",
#      "#75 - Hamilton Ave.\n",
#      "#120 - Curvy Road\n" ]
```

Throw `map(&:chomp)` in there if you want to get rid of the `\n`s.

Comment: This is precisely what I was thinking. Although instead of iteration and then `map` I would just go with `input.split("\n").sort_by....`

Comment: This worked great. @engineersmnky your previous suggestion also worked as well. Is one approach more sound than the other? Asking for future reference... I am going to mark this as answer and will upvote the answer above as well if I can do that.

Comment: @porterhaus I often prefer `each_line` because it simply iterates over the lines instead of loading them all into memory as `split("\n")` does. In this case, however, it doesn't make a difference since `sort_by` will load them all into memory anyway. (Also watch out for Windows-style line endings, i.e. `\r\n`, when you use `split`.)

Comment: Very nice solution!